# Get file extension with a file that has multiple periods

Tags: c#, .net, regex, file, file-extension

Getting the file extension in **C#** is very simple,

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo("c:\\myfile.txt");
MessageBox.Show(file.Extension); // Displays '.txt'
```

However I have files in my app with multiple periods.

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo("c:\\scene_a.scene.xml");
MessageBox.Show(file.Extension); // Displays '.xml'
```

I want to be able to extract the `.scene.xml` portion of the name.

**Update**
The extension should also include the initial `.`

How can I get this from `FileInfo`?

Comment: I used Path v FileInfo so you won't have to Create a new FileInfo Object. But get you the exact results you asked for. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use this regex to extract all characters after dot symbol:

```
\..*
```

---

```
var result = Regex.Match(file.Name, @"\..*").Value;
```

Comment: + 1: I missed he wanted the . at the start too. Works well.

Comment: This worked right away, I also liked @daniel-james-bryars solution.
Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
IO.Path.GetExtension("c:\\scene_a.scene.xml");
```

Ref. [System.IO.Path.GetExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If you want .scene.xml then try this,

```
 FileInfo file = new FileInfo("E:\\scene_a.scene.xml");
 MessageBox.Show(file.FullName.Substring(file.FullName.IndexOf(".")));
```

Comment: OP does not want to get the file Extension IMO.

Comment: @IEnumerable is asking for something different. I agree this is a good way to get the extension - but he's asking for something else.

Comment: but questions title said that need file extension from multiple periods.

Comment: @JigneshThakker: But the question body explains that IEnumerable considers everything after the first period to be the file extension

Comment: Yes the first period is part of the extention. Same as if FileInfo.Extention would return :)

Comment: @IEnumerable, Updated answer you can get .scene.xml with string.Substring function also.

Answer (score 1):

The .xml is the extension the filename is scene_a.scene

If you want to extract scene.xml. You'll need to parse it yourself.

Something like this might do what you want (you'll need to add more code to check for conditions where there isn't a . in the name at all.):

```
String filePath = "c:\\scene_a.scene.xml";

            String myIdeaOfAnExtension = String.Join(".", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath)
                .Split('.')
                .Skip(1));
```

Comment: Yes currently Im just parsing it myself. I was hoping there would be a .NET API that is more robust than mine.

Comment: @IEnumerable - I think it's because (in Windows at least) the ".xml" is the file extension, ".scene.xml" is not.

Comment: true, but even VisualStudio is has multiple `Periods` to tell the App how to view a file. Anyway I guess a good custom library wil do too!

Answer (score 1):

Continue grabbing the extension until there aren't anymore:

```
var extensions = new Stack<string>(); // if you use a list you'll have to reverse it later for FIFO rather than LIFO
string filenameExtension;
while( !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filenameExtension = Path.GetExtension(inputPath)) )
{
    // remember latest extension
    extensions.Push(filenameExtension);
    // remove that extension from consideration
    inputPath = inputPath.Substring(0, inputPath.Length - filenameExtension.Length);
}
filenameExtension = string.Concat(extensions); // already has preceding periods
```

Answer (score 0):

Old I know. Discussions about best practices aside you can do it like this: Linebreaks added for readability.

```
"." + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(
           Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("c:\\scene_a.scene.xml")
      ) 
+ "." +Path.GetExtension("c:\\scene_a.scene.xml")
```

Is it the best way? I don't know but I do know it works in a single line. :) 
[image]